# Setting attributed using the setter adds attribute instead of setting it

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rest, getter-setter

If I try to set an attribute in a TypeScript class using a setter, it will add an attribute instead of changing the existing one. The class looks like

```js
export class User extends Model
{
  private username: string;
  private firstname: string;
  private lastname: string;
  // ...

  public get Username(): string
  {
    return this.username;
  }

  public set Username(value: string)
  {
    this.username = value;
  }
}
```

If I set the firstname by accessing `user.Firstname = 'Tobi';` I can see using `console.log(user)` that the object now contains a Firstname attribute with uppercase first letter.

Angular version: 7.3.8
TypeScript: 3.2.4
NodeJS: 11.11.0
Browsers: Firefox 66.0.3 and Chrome 73.0.3683.103
OS: macOS 10.14.4 (18E226)

```js
// Creating a new object
this.userService.create(this.user).subscribe(
   (user: User) =>
      {
         console.log(user);
         this.user = user;
      }
);
```

```js
// Trying to update the object
tstUpdateUser()
{
    this.user.Firstname = 'Tobi2';
    console.log(this.user);
    this.userService.update(this.user, this.user.Id).subscribe((user: User) =>
        {
            this.user = user;
            console.log('update', this.user);
        });
}
```

```
//Output of Dev console in Firefox
{…}
​
Firstname: "Tobi2"
firstname: "Tobi"
id: 37
​...
```

If I understood the TypeScript getters and setters correctly, the .Firstname property should set the private firstname attribute instead of adding the Firstname attribute.

Comment: Okaayyy... so what are you asking?

Comment: Maybe it's a typo, but it looks like the getter/setter of the class are for a property called "Username", not "Firstname"

Comment: You don't have a `Firstname` property. You have a `firstname` property. You have no accessors called `Firstname`.